# Shell set to bash but running zsh

Tags: macos, bash, shell, zsh

I tried out zsh, but decided to revert to bash because it's what I'm used to. I've set my "Login shell" back to /bin/bash in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Advanced options and have run `chsh -s /bin/bash`. When I run `echo $SHELL` I get the expected "/bin/bash" output. However, the top of my terminal windows says " - ZSH - bash" and when I force an error, like searching for something that doesn't exist, the message seems to indicate that it's still running zsh:
zsh: no matches found: *test

I've tried to force it to be bash in every way I know how. What am I not thinking of? Any/all suggestions appreciated.

Edit:
When I go to close the shell, here's what I see (it says it needs to terminal ZSH).
[image]

Edit 2:
When creating a new window I got this message, which is new. Setopts is in my .bashrc file, so it seems to be set to zsh in whatever is loaded after the .bashrc. The top text has now changed back to the default, so I guess ZSH is no longer the "Active process".
[image]

Comment: What version of macOS are you using? I don't see any "Advanced Options" under System Preferences > Users & Groups.

Comment: Check *Terminal > Preferences > General > Shells open with*.

Comment: Check with `grep $USER /etc/passwd` the last field (with the used shell).

Comment: Advanced Options appears if you unlock w/ a password and then right-click. 
"Shells open with" is set to "Command: /bin/bash". Nothing is printed by "grep $USER /etc/passwd". Thanks for trying, all! :)

Comment: Try the article [How to change bash versions on Mac with Homebrew](https://dev.to/emcain/how-to-change-bash-versions-on-mac-with-homebrew-20o3).

Comment: Does not `chsh -s /bin/bash` work?

Comment: Which terminal application are you using?

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/bash` results in a message that no changes were made. 
I'm using the default "Terminal" in MacOS.

Comment: I've followed the steps in the article and set the shell to the most recent version of bash. I added a photo of what it looks like after doing so (yes, I quit Terminal fully in between installing and taking this).

Comment: Try doing `chsh -s /bin/bash USERNAME` and `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash`. Check for suspicious dot-files `~/.z*` and others including `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that "ZSH" in the window title is in all caps leads me to believe that this is your problem:

[image: screenshot of MacOS Terminal's Preferences window showing the window title setting for the default profile]

To see if this is it:

1. Launch Terminal
2. Go to Preferences
3. Go to the Profiles tab
4. Select the profile marked "Default" in light gray text below its name
5. Go to the Window tab
6. I believe you'll find the text "ZSH" in the Title field. Change it to "waffles and ponies!" or whatever you'd like to see there instead.

These instructions are based on macOS 10.15.6 Catalina. YMMV.

Comment: I agree - given that there is `bash` after `ZSH` in the title, just as if that is the process running. Not sure how ZSH came to be the title for Terminal if this was the case...perhaps another application changed this...somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "ZSH" appears to actually be the "Active process name", not the title (which has always been "Terminal" when I checked it). The "bash" is "Shell Command Name".

Comment: @GenesRus does your Bash rcfile or profile _invoke_ zsh?

Comment: No, I've checked that both are clean. My .bash_profile just sources the .bashrc, which sets PATH, some other environment variables, and a bunch of aliases. I wish it were that easy. :)

Comment: Could you please open a brand new Terminal window, type `ps -f`, then append the complete contents of that terminal window to your question?

Comment: Looking at your update -- I think it's fixed now? By some unknown magic?